# Send byte[] from standalone main to a servlet

Tags: java, servlets, stream

how can I send an `byte[]` from a test client (standalone) to a Servlet?

This is my code:

```
public class Sent
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
    {
        URL url = new URL("http://mydomain.com:8080/demo/myServlet");
        HttpURLConnection oc = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection(); 

        oc.setDoOutput(true);
        oc.setUseCaches(false);

        OutputStream os = oc.getOutputStream();     
        os.write("Hello world".getBytes());
        os.flush();     
        os.close();
    }
}
```

And this is my servlet:

```
@WebServlet("/myServlet")
public class MyServlet extends HttpServlet
{
    private static final long serialVersionUID=1L;

    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException,IOException
    {
        ServletInputStream sis = request.getInputStream();
        int c;
        while( (c=sis.read())>=0 )
        {
            System.out.println((char)c);
        }

        sis.close();
    }
}
```

With this code, the servlet does nothing; by Nothing I mean, it does not write anything on the console... Help.

Thanks.

Comment: Try getting the response code from your `HttpURLConnection` object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you call

```
oc.setDoOutput(true);
```

`HttpURLConnection` assumes you are trying to send a POST request. You don't have a POST request handler, ie. no `doPost()`, so you inherit `HttpServlet`'s implementation which returns a `405 Method Not Allowed` response. You would see that if you did

```
System.out.println(oc.getResponseCode());
```

Instead change your `doGet` to a `doPost`. Or have both, up to you.

Comment: @user3271621 Consider accepting the answer unless there's something missing that you don't understand.

Comment: @user3271621 Can you edit your question and add all the changes you did? It works for me.

Comment: @user3271621 On a related note, be careful with `byte[]` and `String`. Use the appropriate character set.

Comment: Hi Sotirios, just one more thing: Can a servlet, using doGet method, receive and then send bytes coming from an HttpURLConnection?

I ask this because to send bytes through HttpURLConnection, first I need to call: setDoOutput(true); and this call route the request to doPost method.

Are there any way to do this?

Thanks!

Comment: @pablosz Technically it could. Even if you do `setDoOutput()`, you can also call `setRequestMethod` to set the HTTP method. I don't recommend this. The HTTP specification says that GET requests bodies do not need to be read by HTTP servers. The URI of a GET request is the only thing that should identify the requested resource.

Comment: @pablosz The POST method (or even PUT) is appropriate for that.  Consider looking into REST.

Comment: thanks! What I need is send a pair (key,object) to a servlet; then, the servlet persist this pair. Later, other process will send only the key and will wait to receive the related object. 

In this case, the process send an String and receive an Object. 

I was thinking using doPost to let proccess set the pair (key,value) and use doGet method to let process send the key and receive the related object.

Is this wrong? Or, may be, a best way will be use 2 servlets, each one using just doPost method?

Comment: finally I give solution to this problem passing the key through requestProperty. So a single servlet with doPost and doGet methods can handle the wide process. 

doPost method just read the object stream from the client and doGet method just send object stream to the client. 

Thanks a lot, your comments have been very helpful for me. Thanks!